# to insert pipes as delimiters between specific columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to have pipe as delimiters between specific columns in a file.

Input:

```
AQ  92  18-09-2018 00:00:00  29  AR  18-09-2018 05:07:15 18-09-2018 08:06:56
BG  98  18-09-2018 00:00:00  29  AR  18-09-2018 05:07:15 18-09-2018 08:06:56
```

Expected Output:

```
AQ | 92 | 18-09-2018 00:00:00 | 29 | AR | 18-09-2018 05:07:15 | 18-09-2018 08:06:56
BG | 98 | 18-09-2018 00:00:00 | 29 | AR | 18-09-2018 05:07:15 | 18-09-2018 08:06:56
```

I tried using something like below using `awk` but not sure how to proceed further:

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,"|")}1;(NF==3)' file_name
```

Comment: It looks like your input file has two spaces between all the fields except the last two datetimes. Is that right? Why do they only have one space between them, unlike the rest of the fields?

Comment: yes, right..the fields are not evenly spaced in the input file..i've taken this result from a sql query using spool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With gawk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="3 4 21 4 4 21 21"; OFS="|"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6," "$7}' file
```

Output:

```
AQ | 92 | 18-09-2018 00:00:00 | 29 | AR | 18-09-2018 05:07:15 | 18-09-2018 08:06:56
BG | 98 | 18-09-2018 00:00:00 | 29 | AR | 18-09-2018 05:07:15 | 18-09-2018 08:06:56
```

> `FIELDWIDTHS` variable contains a space separated list of numbers, each field is expected to have fixed width, and gawk splits up the record using the specified widths to `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on.
>
> `OFS`: The output field separator

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution, would be helpul..Thanks:-)

Comment: Yes, but I can't do that for a couple of hours.

Comment: Fine.whenever you are free :-)

Answer (score 2):

Except for the last two fields, you have two spaces as delimiters between the fields. So you can set `FS` to `"  "` to match this, and set `OFS` to `" | "` so they'll be converted on output. You only need to do something special with the last field, splitting it up and then turning it into two fields for output.

```
awk -F"  " -v OFS=" | " '{ 
    split($NF, a, " "); 
    $NF = a[1]" "a[2]; 
    $(NF+1) = a[3]" "a[4]; 
    print }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if the fields are evenly spaced?

Comment: Then it's a different problem and needs a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another GNU awk (version >= 4.0) script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[A-Z0-9]{2}|([0-9]{2}-?){4} ([0-9]{2}:?){3}"; OFS=" | "}$1=$1' file
AQ | 92 | 18-09-2018 00:00:00 | 29 | AR | 18-09-2018 05:07:15 | 18-09-2018 08:06:56
BG | 98 | 18-09-2018 00:00:00 | 29 | AR | 18-09-2018 05:07:15 | 18-09-2018 08:06:56
```

This relies on `FPAT` (field pattern) that indicates how the field looks like.

In this case there are 2 patterns:

- `[A-Z0-9]{2}` matches 2 digit or letter
- `([0-9]{2}-?){4} ([0-9]{2}:?){3}` matches the date-time string

The last statement `$1=$1` tells `awk` to re-build the string according to the output field separator `OFS`.

This solution does not rely on the amount of spaces in between the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't need the pipe as a delimiter between the date-time string `18-09-2018 00:00:00`.

Comment: @User123 There isn't any pipe delimeter in between the date-time string. Are you sure you're using _GNU_ awk?

Comment: yes, it's GNU awk only in my system: `GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.`

Comment: @User123 You're using a too old version of awk (from 2009). `FPAT` was introduced in version 4.0 (in 2011)...

Comment: ohk..Thanks for the info :-)